# How to use AJAX in Sweet Alert

Tags: php, sql, ajax, mysqli, sweetalert2

I want the user to confirm if he wants to update his image. I know that I can't use sql with php inside javascript and I have tried on so many ways, but I couldn't make it work, no errors were shown, nothing happened. This code updates the image without even pressing the button. I don't have knowledge on AJAX, so it would be great an example of my code and what it means.

```
    <script>
function rmv_foto() {
event.preventDefault();
  swal({
    title: 'Remover foto de perfil?',
    text: "Essa ação não poderá ser desfeita.",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#F54400',
    confirmButtonText: 'Sim, pode remover!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        var rmv_foto="<?php
        $delete = "UPDATE esc_usuarios_fotos SET img_local = 'images/user.png' WHERE img_usu_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'"; 
        mysqli_query($conexao, $delete) 
        ?>";
        swal(
          'Foto Removida!',
          'Sua foto de perfil foi removida com sucesso.',
          'success'
        ).then(function() {
          location.href = 'perfil.php';
      });
      }
    })
}
</script>
```

How can I properly use ajax to do the update just when user confirms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sweetalert2 Ajax - post input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841570/sweetalert2-ajax-post-input-data)

Comment: I didn't get much info on how I could use my code, since I'm not used with Ajax syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some good research, working like a charm!

```
    function rmv_foto(){
swal({
     title: 'Remover foto de perfil?',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Sim, pode remover!',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
      text: 'Essa ação não poderá ser desfeita.',
      type: 'warning',
      confirmButtonColor: '#F54400',
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
      preConfirm: ()=>{
            $.ajax({
                url: 'rmv.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{},
                success: function(resp)
                      {
                        if(resp) return "ok",
                          swal(
                            'Foto Removida!',
                            'Sua foto de perfil foi removida com sucesso.',
                            'success'
                          ).then(function() {
                            location.href = 'perfil.php';
                          });
                      }
            })
          }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet. Use the preConfirm function, and point to an internal PHP file to do the database interaction

```js
swal({
     title: 'Remover foto de perfil?',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Sim, pode remover!',
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
      preConfirm: ()=>{
            $.ajax({
                url: 'yourPHPfile.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{userID:userVar},
                success: function(resp)
                      {
                        if(resp) return "ok"
                      }
            })

          }

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what should I put in data:{userID:userVar}?, i put the connection and query in the php file, but it didn't worked